# Quick JAVA inheritance question

Tags: java, inheritance

if I have an **abstract** class named Dog with a constructor to set its weight (double) and a class named SpecialDog which extends Dog and has a constructor that accepts a double and passes it to Dog using super().

What (if any) are the differences between:

```
Dog dog = new SpecialDog(12.0);
SpecialDog dog = new SpecialDog(12.0);
Dog dog = new Dog(12.0);
SpecialDog dog = new Dog(12.0);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Besides the answers below, take a look at something called the "Strategy" design pattern.  If you can understand what is going on with that pattern you will see the power of this idea.

Comment: JAVA, I guess it's 1995 again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your questions (they are all different):

```
Dog dog = new SpecialDog(12.0);
```

Here, you are creating a SpecialDog, but using a Dog reference to point to it. The object **is** a special dog, but, unless you downcast your `dog` variable, you are only going to be able to treat `dog` as a `Dog` and not a `SpecialDog`.

```
SpecialDog dog = new SpecialDog(12.0);
```

Here, you are creating a SpecialDog, and using a SpecialDog reference to point to it.

```
Dog dog = new Dog(12.0);
```

This is a compiler error since you can't instantiate abstract classes.

```
SpecialDog dog = new Dog(12.0);
```

This is just a compiler error. You can't assign a super class to a sub class reference. Remember: **inheritance is a "is-a" relationship**. While a **SpecialDog** is always a **Dog**, a **Dog** might not always be a **SpecialDog**.

Comment: Line 4 has 2 errors: constructing object of abstract class and super class assignment

Answer (score 3):

If your `Dog` class is **abstract** then

```
Dog dog = new Dog(12.0);
SpecialDog dog = new Dog(12.0);
```

will not compile.

To answer a question in your comment:

If you use `Dog` variable you will only be able to use methods of `Dog` class.
Compiler will generate an error if you would try to use methods of the `SpecialDog` in this case.

Comment: Thought so. Thanks :)
Will it change anything when it comes to dog if I declare it as a Dog or SpecialDog. What I mean is, if dog is declared as being of type Dog, can I use methods found in the class SpecialDog like this: dog.someMethod()

Comment: Only if the methods in "SpecialDog" are also part of "Dog" (meaning the inherited methods).  Also, those methods in "Dog" must be public.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `Dog dog = new SpecialDog(12.0);` promotes [polymorphism](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) in your code. In another word, it promotes extendability in your APIs in the future.

For example, if your method accepts `Dog` as a parameter, then any dog can be passed into that method:-

```
// you can pass SpecialDog, SkinnyDog, UglyDog into this API to make the dog fat
public void makeMeFat(Dog dog) {
   ...
}
```

However, if the method accepts only certain type of dog, then only that dog can be used in that method:-

```
// you can only pass SpecialDog into this API
public void makeMeFat(Special dog) {
   ...
}
```

If you make `Dog` to be an abstract class, then you cannot use it to create another Dog because an abstract class has only partial implementation. So, it is not possible to create a dog with an abstract class. In real world, you might get a dog with 3 legs with an abstract `Dog`... but at least in the programming world, you get a compilation error because the compiler God doesn't want a 3-legged dog. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a SpecialDog, assign it to a Dog variable, you need to cast if you want to use SpecialDog only functions.

```
Dog dog = new SpecialDog(12.0);
```

Create a SpecialDog and assign it to a SpecialDog variable. Nothing special.

```
SpecialDog dog = new SpecialDog(12.0);
```

The remaining two try to create instances of an abstract class, and will not compile.